# Linux telnet shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to read multiple hosts and ports from a text file (ip.txt) and check if they are connected/failed to connect/timed out, and echo the responses to Telnet_Success.txt/Telnet_Failure.txt/Telnet_Refused.txt files

I have tried the following script, it simply shows all the connection results as failed, but when checking manually one by one, I find some of them connected. any help is appreciated.
Here is the script:

```
>Telnet_Success.txt
>Telnet_Refused.txt
>Telnet_Failure.txt
file=ip.txt
while read line ; do
  ip=$( echo "$line" |cut -d ' ' -f1 )
  port=$( echo "$line" |cut -d ' ' -f2 )
  if telnet -c $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
  echo "$ip $port Connected" >> Telnet_Success.txt
  elif telnet -c $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q refused; then
  echo "$ip $port Refused" >> Telnet_Refused.txt
  else
  echo "$ip $port Failed" >> Telnet_Failure.txt
  fi
 done < ${file}
```

Comment: It would help with debugging to store the output from `telnet` in a variable (like `result=$(telnet -c $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1)`), then you can print that and see exactly what's there before comparing it. It also means you only have to run `telnet` once, and you can then check that result for "Escape" and "refused". BTW, I'd also replace reading the line into a single variable and then using `cut` to get fields from it, but using `read`'s built-in capability to split fields with `while read ip port ignoredJunk; do`...

Comment: Look into the `expect` program.

Comment: I made some modifications based on Gordon Davisson's comments and it now gives me correct result, BUT, for some reason it skips the last line of the ip.txt file and ignores the last pair of hostname and port. so here is my new code:

Comment: >Telnet_Success.txt
>Telnet_Refused.txt
>Telnet_Failure.txt
file=ip.txt
while read desthost destport ignoredJunk; do
  ip=$( echo "$desthost")
  port=$( echo "$destport")
  result=$(telnet -c $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1)
  if echo "$result" | grep -q 'Escape'; then
  echo "$ip $port Connected" >> Telnet_Success.txt
  elif echo "$result" | grep -q 'refused'; then
  echo "$ip $port Refused" >> Telnet_Refused.txt
  else
  echo "$ip $port Failed" >> Telnet_Failure.txt
fi
done < ${file}

Comment: You should [edit] your question to update it rather than post code in comments; as you can see, it doesn't work very well.

Comment: Does the last line of the input file lack its line feed?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you exactly what's failing from the diagnostics you have provided, but it's definitely a problem that you attempt to call `telnet` multiple times - you could get different outcomes each time, producing bugs which are hard to troubleshoot. You also have some stylistic issues in your code.

Try this refactoring; see the inline comments.

```
>Telnet_Success.txt
>Telnet_Refused.txt
>Telnet_Failure.txt
# Why use a variable for something you only reference once anyway?
file=ip.txt
# Use the shell's field splitting facility
# Cope with missing final newline; see
# https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21
while read -r ip port _ || [[ -n $port ]]; do
  # Run telnet once, capture result for analysis 
  output=$(telnet -c "$ip" "$port" </dev/null 2>&1)
  case $output in
    *Escape*)
        echo "$ip $port Connected" >> Telnet_Success.txt;;
  *refused*)
        echo "$ip $port Refused" >> Telnet_Refused.txt;;
  *)
        echo "$ip $port Failed" >> Telnet_Failure.txt;;
  esac
# Always double quote file name variables, just in case
done < "${file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi looks like the telnet command is the culprit
should be "telnet ip port" not "telnet -c ip port"

```
file=ip.txt
while read line
do
  ip=$( echo "$line" |cut -d ' ' -f1 )
  port=$( echo "$line" |cut -d ' ' -f2 )
  if  telnet  $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape 
  then  
    echo "$ip $port Connected" >> Telnet_Success.txt
  elif  telnet  $ip $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q refused 
  then
    echo "$ip $port Refused" >> Telnet_Refused.txt
  else
    echo "$ip $port Failed" >> Telnet_Failure.txt
  fi
done < ${file}
```

Comment: `telnet -c ip port` is legitimate. From the manual: " -c Disables the reading of the user's .telnetrc file."

Comment: Hi just check what envirment are you using im using

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename:xenial

with -c it gives
```telnet -c rainmaker.wunderground.com 23
telnet: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: telnet [-4] [-6] [-8] [-E] [-L] [-a] [-d] [-e char] [-l user]
 [-n tracefile] [ -b addr ] [-r] [host-name [port]] ```